# WPF - RichTextBox, make elements focusable

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox that contains some text and another uiElements like ComboBox, etc.
I need to focus the Combobox when the cursor riches it. Now it just jumps over it. I can focus the combobox using the Tab button, but I need to focus it when I browse the richtextbox using the cursor.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if what you need is a condition, that if satisfied, you call `yourComboBox.Focus()` then handle SelectionChange event and use CaretPosition.GetOffsetToPosition() method. Something like this:

```
 void RichTextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int y = yourRTB.CaretPosition.GetOffsetToPosition(yourUI.ElementStart);
        if (y == 1 || y == -3)
        {
            yourComboBox.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Of course you can change the condition to satisfy your needs.